# What is the use of electronics in Darwin Project?

Tags: darwin-project

Watching one of my streamers play Darwin Project, which is something like PUBG, but one player is an overseer, giving buffs around.

But I see players go for some kind of tower, and I think it's called electronics?

But I don't really see the use of the electronics? Watching an overseer playthough it's not really clear what advantage does electronics do.

So what is the use of electronics in the Darwin Project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an electronic appears on the field, an announcement is made and the electronic gets marked on the mini-map so that players get lured into a bloodbath as contestants fight for the upper hand. For the lucky recipient of the electronic, they’ll be able to craft a permanent ability that will be usable throughout the rest of the game. Electronics can be crafted to give players temporary camouflage, invincibility, or my personal favorite, construct a turret that will fire arrows at nearby players as you lounge by the campfire.

Credit: https://waytoomanygames.com/2018/01/22/darwin-project-first-impressions/